# Building a Shiny App to Dynamically Output an Optimal Fantasy Football Roster while Drafting

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a shiny app that allows me to dynamically optimize a roster for fantasy football drafting. I have working code to build a shiny app that inputs a data file titled "players" with data below:

```
> dput(players)
structure(list(Player = c("Josh Allen", "Patrick Mahomes", "Justin Herbert", 
"Lamar Jackson", "Kyler Murray", "Jalen Hurts", "Tom Brady", 
"Dak Prescott", "Joe Burrow", "Russell Wilson", "Aaron Rodgers", 
"Trey Lance", "Matthew Stafford", "Kirk Cousins", "Derek Carr", 
"Tua Tagovailoa", "Justin Fields", "Trevor Lawrence", "Ryan Tannehill", 
"Daniel Jones", "Matt Ryan", "Jameis Winston", "Carson Wentz", 
"Mac Jones", "Jared Goff", "Zach Wilson", "Davis Mills", "Baker Mayfield", 
"Marcus Mariota", "Deshaun Watson", "Mitchell Trubisky", "Geno Smith", 
"Drew Lock", "Kenny Pickett", "Jacoby Brissett", "Desmond Ridder", 
"Travis Kelce", "Mark Andrews", "Kyle Pitts", "Darren Waller", 
"George Kittle", "Dalton Schultz", "T.J. Hockenson", "Dallas Goedert", 
"Zach Ertz", "Dawson Knox", "Hunter Henry", "Mike Gesicki", "Pat Freiermuth", 
"Cole Kmet", "Irv Smith Jr.", "Noah Fant", "Tyler Higbee", "David Njoku", 
"Albert Okwuegbunam", "Gerald Everett", "Robert Tonyan", "Jonathan Taylor", 
"Christian McCaffrey", "Derrick Henry", "Austin Ekeler", "Dalvin Cook", 
"Joe Mixon", "Najee Harris", "Alvin Kamara", "D'Andre Swift", 
"Leonard Fournette", "Saquon Barkley", "Aaron Jones", "Nick Chubb", 
"James Conner", "Javonte Williams", "Ezekiel Elliott", "David Montgomery", 
"Cam Akers", "Travis Etienne Jr.", "Breece Hall", "J.K. Dobbins", 
"Josh Jacobs", "Antonio Gibson", "Elijah Mitchell", "AJ Dillon", 
"Cordarrelle Patterson", "Damien Harris", "Miles Sanders", "Clyde Edwards-Helaire", 
"Tony Pollard", "Devin Singletary", "Kareem Hunt", "Chase Edmonds", 
"Rashaad Penny", "Rhamondre Stevenson", "Kenneth Walker III", 
"Melvin Gordon III", "Darrell Henderson Jr.", "James Robinson", 
"James Cook", "Dameon Pierce", "Michael Carter", "Jamaal Williams", 
"Nyheim Hines", "J.D. McKissic", "Kenneth Gainwell", "Alexander Mattison", 
"Isaiah Spiller", "Raheem Mostert", "Mark Ingram II", "Marlon Mack", 
"Brian Robinson", "Gus Edwards", "Rex Burkhead", "Rachaad White", 
"Khalil Herbert", "Damien Williams", "Tyler Allgeier", "D'Onta Foreman", 
"Jerick McKinnon", "Cooper Kupp", "Justin Jefferson", "Ja'Marr Chase", 
"Davante Adams", "Stefon Diggs", "Deebo Samuel", "CeeDee Lamb", 
"Mike Evans", "Tyreek Hill", "Tee Higgins", "Keenan Allen", "DJ Moore", 
"A.J. Brown", "Michael Pittman Jr.", "Mike Williams", "Brandin Cooks", 
"Jaylen Waddle", "Diontae Johnson", "Terry McLaurin", "DK Metcalf", 
"Courtland Sutton", "Amon-Ra St. Brown", "Darnell Mooney", "Allen Robinson II", 
"Marquise Brown", "Amari Cooper", "Gabriel Davis", "Chris Godwin", 
"Michael Thomas", "Jerry Jeudy", "Adam Thielen", "JuJu Smith-Schuster", 
"Hunter Renfrow", "Rashod Bateman", "Elijah Moore", "Tyler Lockett", 
"Christian Kirk", "Robert Woods", "DeVonta Smith", "Drake London", 
"Allen Lazard", "Brandon Aiyuk", "Chase Claypool", "Kadarius Toney", 
"Tyler Boyd", "Garrett Wilson", "DeVante Parker", "Chris Olave", 
"Kenny Golladay", "Jakobi Meyers", "Russell Gage", "Marquez Valdes-Scantling", 
"DeAndre Hopkins", "Marvin Jones Jr.", "Treylon Burks", "Michael Gallup", 
"Robbie Anderson", "DJ Chark", "Jahan Dotson", "Mecole Hardman"
), Position = c("QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR"), FantasyPoints = c(445, 410, 407, 348, 
351, 359, 354, 364, 402, 368, 353, 347, 349, 335, 366, 325, 297, 
313, 273, 283, 302, 284, 275, 296, 291, 0, 247, 286, 276, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 269, 0, 0, 252, 231, 206, 171, 185, 177, 174, 169, 169, 
171, 139, 131, 170, 170, 162, 129, 162, 119, 130, 126, 130, 340, 
285, 260, 278, 277, 271, 277, 247, 271, 225, 247, 249, 230, 196, 
268, 205, 199, 213, 231, 220, 177, 176, 159, 178, 185, 155, 181, 
157, 190, 177, 164, 156, 166, 169, 179, 158, 129, 147, 99, 158, 
176, 150, 100, 157, 128, 156, 124, 98, 95, 75, 90, 136, 80, 82, 
143, 128, 0, 147, 97, 63, 326, 337, 308, 299, 269, 267, 271, 
242, 243, 241, 239, 243, 242, 244, 209, 220, 233, 239, 221, 198, 
221, 209, 220, 209, 218, 178, 224, 183, 186, 203, 188, 164, 207, 
211, 202, 173, 188, 163, 199, 171, 181, 182, 140, 170, 175, 144, 
142, 164, 147, 131, 170, 160, 182, 136, 153, 157, 152, 148, 175, 
144), DraftValue = c(31, 23, 20, 15, 16, 14, 16, 11, 12, 10, 
10, 3, 7, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 37, 34, 22, 20, 17, 16, 12, 11, 9, 6, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 55, 44, 48, 38, 38, 40, 38, 36, 
34, 34, 33, 27, 30, 28, 27, 23, 21, 23, 21, 19, 18, 10, 15, 16, 
16, 12, 12, 14, 13, 10, 11, 12, 8, 9, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 48, 41, 
40, 37, 31, 34, 29, 30, 28, 28, 26, 24, 26, 23, 23, 22, 21, 20, 
18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 17, 15, 15, 17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 13, 12, 
12, 12, 11, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-177L))
```

and outputs the lineup that will maximize points scored, while constrained to the user set draft budget and roster requirements (number of QB, RB, WR, flex) BUT I need to add functionality to use this while drafting as things change. I have the below code as well that builds the shiny app and outputs the optimal lineup and it updates automatically if I modify the roster numbers BUT it does not currently remove a player from the data set when I click the "Remove Player" button. When I click that button, the table in shiny showing the roster disappears and I get an error. I can't figure out in the code why:

```
library(shiny)
library(lpSolve)

# Define the UI for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Fantasy Football Lineup Optimizer"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("num_qb", "Enter the number of QBs:", 1),
      numericInput("num_rb", "Enter the number of RBs:", 2),
      numericInput("num_wr", "Enter the number of WRs:", 3),
      numericInput("num_te", "Enter the number of TEs:", 1),
      numericInput("num_value", "Enter your draft budget:", 200),
      numericInput("num_players", "Adding in your flex spots, enter the total number of starters:", 9),
      actionButton("optimize", "Optimize Lineup"),
      actionButton("remove", "Remove Player"),
      textInput("player", "Enter the name of the player to remove:")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("team")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  players <- structure(list(Player = c("Josh Allen", "Patrick Mahomes", "Justin Herbert", 
"Lamar Jackson", "Kyler Murray", "Jalen Hurts", "Tom Brady", 
"Dak Prescott", "Joe Burrow", "Russell Wilson", "Aaron Rodgers", 
"Trey Lance", "Matthew Stafford", "Kirk Cousins", "Derek Carr", 
"Tua Tagovailoa", "Justin Fields", "Trevor Lawrence", "Ryan Tannehill", 
"Daniel Jones", "Matt Ryan", "Jameis Winston", "Carson Wentz", 
"Mac Jones", "Jared Goff", "Zach Wilson", "Davis Mills", "Baker Mayfield", 
"Marcus Mariota", "Deshaun Watson", "Mitchell Trubisky", "Geno Smith", 
"Drew Lock", "Kenny Pickett", "Jacoby Brissett", "Desmond Ridder", 
"Travis Kelce", "Mark Andrews", "Kyle Pitts", "Darren Waller", 
"George Kittle", "Dalton Schultz", "T.J. Hockenson", "Dallas Goedert", 
"Zach Ertz", "Dawson Knox", "Hunter Henry", "Mike Gesicki", "Pat Freiermuth", 
"Cole Kmet", "Irv Smith Jr.", "Noah Fant", "Tyler Higbee", "David Njoku", 
"Albert Okwuegbunam", "Gerald Everett", "Robert Tonyan", "Jonathan Taylor", 
"Christian McCaffrey", "Derrick Henry", "Austin Ekeler", "Dalvin Cook", 
"Joe Mixon", "Najee Harris", "Alvin Kamara", "D'Andre Swift", 
"Leonard Fournette", "Saquon Barkley", "Aaron Jones", "Nick Chubb", 
"James Conner", "Javonte Williams", "Ezekiel Elliott", "David Montgomery", 
"Cam Akers", "Travis Etienne Jr.", "Breece Hall", "J.K. Dobbins", 
"Josh Jacobs", "Antonio Gibson", "Elijah Mitchell", "AJ Dillon", 
"Cordarrelle Patterson", "Damien Harris", "Miles Sanders", "Clyde Edwards-Helaire", 
"Tony Pollard", "Devin Singletary", "Kareem Hunt", "Chase Edmonds", 
"Rashaad Penny", "Rhamondre Stevenson", "Kenneth Walker III", 
"Melvin Gordon III", "Darrell Henderson Jr.", "James Robinson", 
"James Cook", "Dameon Pierce", "Michael Carter", "Jamaal Williams", 
"Nyheim Hines", "J.D. McKissic", "Kenneth Gainwell", "Alexander Mattison", 
"Isaiah Spiller", "Raheem Mostert", "Mark Ingram II", "Marlon Mack", 
"Brian Robinson", "Gus Edwards", "Rex Burkhead", "Rachaad White", 
"Khalil Herbert", "Damien Williams", "Tyler Allgeier", "D'Onta Foreman", 
"Jerick McKinnon", "Cooper Kupp", "Justin Jefferson", "Ja'Marr Chase", 
"Davante Adams", "Stefon Diggs", "Deebo Samuel", "CeeDee Lamb", 
"Mike Evans", "Tyreek Hill", "Tee Higgins", "Keenan Allen", "DJ Moore", 
"A.J. Brown", "Michael Pittman Jr.", "Mike Williams", "Brandin Cooks", 
"Jaylen Waddle", "Diontae Johnson", "Terry McLaurin", "DK Metcalf", 
"Courtland Sutton", "Amon-Ra St. Brown", "Darnell Mooney", "Allen Robinson II", 
"Marquise Brown", "Amari Cooper", "Gabriel Davis", "Chris Godwin", 
"Michael Thomas", "Jerry Jeudy", "Adam Thielen", "JuJu Smith-Schuster", 
"Hunter Renfrow", "Rashod Bateman", "Elijah Moore", "Tyler Lockett", 
"Christian Kirk", "Robert Woods", "DeVonta Smith", "Drake London", 
"Allen Lazard", "Brandon Aiyuk", "Chase Claypool", "Kadarius Toney", 
"Tyler Boyd", "Garrett Wilson", "DeVante Parker", "Chris Olave", 
"Kenny Golladay", "Jakobi Meyers", "Russell Gage", "Marquez Valdes-Scantling", 
"DeAndre Hopkins", "Marvin Jones Jr.", "Treylon Burks", "Michael Gallup", 
"Robbie Anderson", "DJ Chark", "Jahan Dotson", "Mecole Hardman"
), Position = c("QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "RB", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "WR", "WR", "WR"), FantasyPoints = c(445, 410, 407, 348, 
351, 359, 354, 364, 402, 368, 353, 347, 349, 335, 366, 325, 297, 
313, 273, 283, 302, 284, 275, 296, 291, 0, 247, 286, 276, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 269, 0, 0, 252, 231, 206, 171, 185, 177, 174, 169, 169, 
171, 139, 131, 170, 170, 162, 129, 162, 119, 130, 126, 130, 340, 
285, 260, 278, 277, 271, 277, 247, 271, 225, 247, 249, 230, 196, 
268, 205, 199, 213, 231, 220, 177, 176, 159, 178, 185, 155, 181, 
157, 190, 177, 164, 156, 166, 169, 179, 158, 129, 147, 99, 158, 
176, 150, 100, 157, 128, 156, 124, 98, 95, 75, 90, 136, 80, 82, 
143, 128, 0, 147, 97, 63, 326, 337, 308, 299, 269, 267, 271, 
242, 243, 241, 239, 243, 242, 244, 209, 220, 233, 239, 221, 198, 
221, 209, 220, 209, 218, 178, 224, 183, 186, 203, 188, 164, 207, 
211, 202, 173, 188, 163, 199, 171, 181, 182, 140, 170, 175, 144, 
142, 164, 147, 131, 170, 160, 182, 136, 153, 157, 152, 148, 175, 
144), DraftValue = c(31, 23, 20, 15, 16, 14, 16, 11, 12, 10, 
10, 3, 7, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 37, 34, 22, 20, 17, 16, 12, 11, 9, 6, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 55, 44, 48, 38, 38, 40, 38, 36, 
34, 34, 33, 27, 30, 28, 27, 23, 21, 23, 21, 19, 18, 10, 15, 16, 
16, 12, 12, 14, 13, 10, 11, 12, 8, 9, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 56, 48, 41, 
40, 37, 31, 34, 29, 30, 28, 28, 26, 24, 26, 23, 23, 22, 21, 20, 
18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 17, 15, 15, 17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 13, 12, 
12, 12, 11, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-177L))
  
  # Create a new column indicating the player's position
  players$QB <- ifelse(players$Position == "QB", 1, 0)
  players$RB <- ifelse(players$Position == "RB", 1, 0)
  players$WR <- ifelse(players$Position == "WR", 1, 0)
  players$TE <- ifelse(players$Position == "TE", 1, 0)
  players$Total <- 1
  rv <- reactiveValues(players=players)
  
  # Define the objective function (maximize fantasy points)
  obj <- players$FantasyPoints
  
  # Define the constraints (position limits and draft value limit)
  con <- reactive({
    matrix(c(
        # QB constraint
        rv$players$QB,
        # RB constraint
        rv$players$RB,
        # WR constraint
        rv$players$WR,
        # TE constraint
        rv$players$TE,
        # Draft value constraint
        rv$players$DraftValue,
        #Total players constraint
        rv$players$Total
    ), ncol = nrow(rv$players), byrow = TRUE)
})

  
  # Define the variables for the lp
  dir <- c("<=", rep(">=",3),"<=","<=")
  
  # Define the function to run when the "remove" button is pressed
observeEvent(input$remove, {
  # Subset the rv$players dataframe to exclude the player to be removed
  rv$players <- rv$players[rv$players$Player != input$player,]
})

  
  # Define the function to run when the "optimize" button is pressed
  optimizeLineup <- reactive({
    input$remove
    rhs <- reactive({
  c(input$num_qb, input$num_rb, input$num_wr, input$num_te, input$num_value, input$num_players)
})
    result <- lp("max", obj, con(), dir, rhs(), all.bin = TRUE)
    rv$players[result$solution == 1,]
  })
  
  # Show the optimal team in a table when the "optimize" button is pressed
output$team <- renderTable({
  input$remove
  optimizeLineup()
})
}
# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The app doesn't work and gives the error:

```
Warning: Error in vectbl_as_row_location: Can't subset rows with `result$solution == 1`.
✖ Logical subscript `result$solution == 1` must be size 1 or 176, not 177.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want values to change, you need to make `players` a reactive object otherwise other events in your app will not be notified when it's value changes. It can't just be a regular object in your global environment. If you are new to shiny, maybe start out with an introduction to reactivity: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con/reactivity-pt-1-joe-cheng/

Comment: You need to make `players` reactive to make `optimizeLineUp()` respond to changes in `players`. BTW, I would name it `obtimisedLineup` because it’s an object. Objects are nouns, functions are verbs. A small change, but I believe it will improve the readability of your code.

Comment: @MrFlick: snap, and almost a dead heat. :=)

Comment: @Limey i guess i thought i was doing that. I keep trying to try in different ways, but I must be misunderstanding something because it just starts breaking earlier. Can someone help with showing me what needs to be done to make "players" reactive properly?

Answer (score 1):

Untested code, since your example is not reproducible.  (We don't (I hope, for your sake!) have access to your C: drive...)

After

```
players$Total <- 1
```

add

```
rv <- reactiveValues(players=players)
```

And then change every subsequent reference to `players` to `rv$players`.

Alternatively, change

```
removePlayer <- eventReactive(input$remove, {
    players <- players[players$Player != input$player,]
    players
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

to

```
observeEvent(input$remove, {
  players <- players[players$Player != input$player,]
})
```

and

```
output$team <- renderTable({
    optimizeLineup()
  })
```

to

```
output$team <- renderTable({
  input$remove
  optimizeLineup()
})
```

In the first option, you are making `players` directly reactive.  This would be my preference.  In the second, you are keeping `players` non-reactive, but more appropriately (IMHO) using `observeEvent` to trigger changes to `players` and introducing a dependency on `input$remove` to your `renderTable()`.  I believe this is more appropriate than `eventReactive` since you never reference `removePlayer` and thus are using `eventReactive` for its indirect rather than direct effects.  Your code is therefore more opaque.

If neither of these suggestions work, remove the references to `readxl` and its component functions and post the result of `dput(players)` [or `dput(head(players, n))` where `n` is an integer that allows sufficient information in the output to provide a usable example.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

**Edit**

I don't have `lpSolve` installed and don't wish to install it simply to solve someone else's problem.  Here is a working example that "optimises" simply by displaying the first five rows of the `players` reactive and appears to work as expected.  You should be able to figure out what's going on from there.

As an aside, posting an error your get from code that you don't provide is less than helpful.  Also, please don't provide additional information in comments in the future: edit the your original post instead.

```
library(shiny)

# Define the UI for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Fantasy Football Lineup Optimizer"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("num_qb", "Enter the number of QBs:", 1),
      numericInput("num_rb", "Enter the number of RBs:", 2),
      numericInput("num_wr", "Enter the number of WRs:", 3),
      numericInput("num_te", "Enter the number of TEs:", 1),
      numericInput("num_value", "Enter your draft budget:", 200),
      numericInput("num_players", "Adding in your flex spots, enter the total number of starters:", 9),
      actionButton("optimize", "Optimize Lineup"),
      actionButton("remove", "Remove Player"),
      textInput("player", "Enter the name of the player to remove:")
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("team")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  players <- structure(list(Player = c("Josh Allen", "Patrick Mahomes", "Justin Herbert", "Lamar Jackson", "Kyler Murray"), Position = c("QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB"), FantasyPoints = c(445, 410, 407, 348, 351), DraftValue = c(31, 23, 20, 15, 16)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
  
  # Create a new column indicating the player's position
  players$QB <- ifelse(players$Position == "QB", 1, 0)
  players$RB <- ifelse(players$Position == "RB", 1, 0)
  players$WR <- ifelse(players$Position == "WR", 1, 0)
  players$TE <- ifelse(players$Position == "TE", 1, 0)
  players$Total <- 1
  rv <- reactiveValues(players=players)

  
  # Define the function to run when the "remove" button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    rv$players <- players[players$Player != input$player,]
 })
  
  # Show the optimal team in a table when the "optimize" button is pressed
  output$team <- renderTable({
    rv$players %>% head(5)
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As an aside, using the `DT` package will allow you to manipulate the players table directly by mouse clicks, without the need to type player names individually.

Comment: I made the requested edits to the original post - getting a new error now. It seems to be failing when I remove the player as the error code suggests the new data set size is not matching the result

Comment: You appear not to have updated the input to your `lpSolve` calls.  `con` needs to be reactive.

Comment: updated the post with this fix plus the resulting error. Not sure where the issue is?